# jquery issue with chekbox

Tags: jquery, html

This is my html checkbox --

```
<input type="checkbox" id="export_1_field_title" value="title">
```

in jquery, i want to check whether checkbox is checked or not, if check then will read the value, so this is my query --

```
                var title = '';
                if($("#export_1_field_title").is("checked"))
                {
                    title = 'title';
                }
                alert('Here '+title);
```

but not able to read the checkbox, kindly suggest any changes required

Comment: Use `$("#export_1_field_title").is(":checked")`. Don't forget the `:`.

Comment: you can use it like this too
`if($("#export_1_field_title:checked").length > 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if it is checked (You forgot `:`) :

```
$("#export_1_field_title").is(":checked")
```

To extract the value :

```
title = $("#export_1_field_title").val();
```

Comment: solved, thnx bro